# Flex mx Image source path at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm wading through a Flex AIR desktop project that someone else wrote.  The original author has used several mx.controls.Image components.  Runtime image paths assigned like this:

```
image.source = "/assets/book.png";
```

It doesn't work - I just get the broken image icon.

I've never used the above approach in my own code.  Personally, I've always used compile-time embedded images or URLLoader/Loader for runtime images.

So, I'd like to learn how to get this image path approach working.

I wrote a simple test program.  Here is my .mxml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <pf:LearningAS xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
      xmlns:pf="com.powerflasher.*">
      <mx:Image id="myImage"/>
 </pf:LearningAS>
```

Here is my connected .as

```
public class LearningAS extends WindowedApplication {

    public var myImage:Image;

    public function LearningAS() {
        super();
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, init);
    }

    protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
        myImage.source = '/assets/myimage.png';
    }
}
```

I also added the src/assets folder to AIR package contents.  And I added -use-network=false to my compiler directives.  (I'm using FDT, and Flex 4.6).

Comment: Is this at runtime in debug mode or runtime after you run the installer for your program?

Comment: Running locally in ADL simulator.  Both run or debug in the simulator.

Comment: What is that connected .as means? You are providing **id** for **mx:Image** as **myImage** and again defining the same **myImage** in **LearningAs**.

Comment: By the magic of Flex this works.  I've connected the .mxml and LearningAS.as by nesting all my mxml inside: <pf:LearningAS....

That syntax with myImage, ensures that the myImage var inside the .as is tied to the <mx:Image id="myImage"/>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - Cracked it, with some help from the Flex mailing list.

I had to copy my assets folder into my bin folder.  So that the paths were relative to the .swf.  (Actually, I've done this for previous AS3 projects - but I assumed that packaging assets folder for AIR would cover this.)

Anyway - problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are giving incorrect image path reference instead of  `myImage.source = '/assets/myimage.png';` try  `myImage.source = 'assets/myimage.png';`

Hope it work for you.